# a relation between a table and distinct table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, erd, distinct-values

I want to show a relation between a table and a distinct table. 
Here is a scenario.
I have a table crime and another containing crime_rape.

```
table crime
id   type  name
001  VNC   Rape
002  CCD   Theft
003  VNC   Rape
004  ATA   Rape
```

table crime_rape

```
id   type
001  VNC
004  ATA
```

Can there be any relation between them? the primary key of table crime for VNC has 001 & 003 but since crime_rape needs to be distinct, what foreign key can i show for VNC in table crime_rape ??

_ i just have a basic knowledge in DB.
Your help is appreciated . Thank you

Comment: What does "needs to be distinct" mean? *Why* does your second table only have (001,VNC) and not (003,VNC)? Please explain how to decide what rows go into it in terms of what rows are in `crime`.

Answer (score 1):

In your crime table data is repeated so if you want one to many relation you should create third table for relation like

table crime

id   type  name

001  VNC   Rape

002  CCD   Theft

003  ATA   Rape

crime_rape

id   type

001  VNC

004  ATA

table crime_rape_relation

id   crime_id  rape_id

001    001     001

002    003     004

Comment: Please make the effor to format your tables in a readable way.

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.
So you wasting your resource to make two similar table. To make something like second table just type this `SELECT DISTINCT id, type FROM crime;`

Comment: The DISTINCT implements, roughly, a relational operation called "projection".

Comment: @  Surya Tanamas & @Wang'lPakhrin  But` DISTINCT id, type` returns distinct (id,type) pairs, so it does not generate the second table.

Comment: @philipxy why needed of second table to be there ? How about data syncronize between first and second table ? How to sure that all data is syncronize between first and second table ???

Comment: @ Surya Tanamas (& @Wang'lPakhrin) I don't understand the point of your questions. *I* don't know what the 2nd is supposed to be. Ask the op, like I did. So far, we know that there is an inclusion dependency on type. (And probably on id & type.) (See my answer.) And we know that *your query doesn't return the 2nd table*. Moreover even if the 2nd always has *only* subrows from the 1st, that doesn't mean that the 2nd is always the same view/query of the 1st; I suspect that's what they mean by "distinct". So "yes your logic makes sense" is also wrong. (But it might apply to *some* of the 2nd.)

Answer (score 0):

By "relation" I guess you mean "relationship" which in some ER-oriented methods means "foreign key".

The constraint that you want for `type` is an "inclusion dependency" constraint. It says that the subrow values of some column list must appear as subrow values of a referenced column list. An SQL foriegn key constraint is an inclusion dependency constraint referencing a (super)key (ie unique set of columns). SQL doesn't have a way to declaratively enforce inclusion dependencies in general.

But probably you actually want the *pair* of `(id,type)` values to appear in `crime`. If so then in your second table:

```
constraint foreign key (id,type) references crime (id,type)
```

Because `crime` `id` is unique, every column set including it is unique. But SQL requires that a foreign key's referenced column list be explicitly declared as a key. So in `crime` you need:

```
constraint unique not null (id,type)
```